# Visual studio compiler optimisation for type casting in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-optimization

I had the following statement in code:

```
int a = (int)( (float)(b * 1000) / (float)c + .5f );
```

where `b` is an `int` as well,
and `c` is an `unsigned int`with a constant value (of 15 in my test runs)

This statement was inside a while loop where `b` gets incremented by 1 on each iteration.

This code was working fine till I decided to switch on the optimisation flags (maximise speed) in Visual studio. After which, `a` would randomly run into an overflow (i.e it had a value of `-2147483647`). On investigating further this overflow used to happen at different values of `b`. The values of b where the overflow happened were between 9-12 in the test runs I observed.

What solved the problem was making the a small change as illustrated below:

```
int a = (int)( (b * 1000.f) / c + .5f );
```

Any ideas on how did this help? It is working fine but I can't figure out why?

Edit: Adding some more information based on comments:

While logging, I observed that :

`(float)(b * 1000) / (float)c + .5f`

was being evaluated to a really large value , which when type-casted to `int` was leading to the overflow. Individually, `float(b*1000)` and `float(c)` were being calculated correctly however.

Comment: what are the types of b and c?

Comment: @mustafagonul "where `b` is an `int` as well, and `c` is an `unsigned int`"

Comment: And it is important which optimization flags you are using. The behavior is totally implementation defined. It is obvious, you are making an overflow mistake. But I don't know, when you switch the optimization flags off, it runs in a right way.

Comment: Is it possible, that `a` was not really overflowing with optimizations enabled, just that the debugger was unable to report its true value? Did you see any actual verifiable evidence of `a` being incorrect other than the debugger reported value?

Comment: I was using the /O2 optimisation flag (Maximise Speed)

Comment: @Rotem I was using `a` elsewhere in the app and hence I knew it was `a` overflowing that caused the crash in my app. besides, I was also logging the value to a file and I observed the value of `-2147483647`

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook Ok, just making sure.

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook Did you also log the values of `b` and `c` to make sure that their values were what you assumed?

Comment: @molbdnilo I did. `b` and `c` were as expected as well. 
I couldn't figure out what were the optimisation flags changing so I logged everything I could. Actually, that reminds me to add some more information that will be relevant to the question

Comment: @AndyT  Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 1):

`b * 1000` is most likely overflowing the `int` type; the behaviour of doing this is *undefined*.

Drop all those obfuscating casts, and use

`b * 1000.0 / c + 0.5`

instead. `1000.0` is a `double` literal and causes the first term to be evaluated in floating point.

You ought to check the size of the expression before converting back to `int`, especially if `c` is small. `std::numeric_limits` is useful for that.

Comment: Same question, how do you explain an overflow for values of `b` between 9-12?

Comment: `c` also comes into play here. What is its value?

Comment: It doesn't, because it was cast to `float` in the original statement.

Comment: Um, it does when converting the whole thing to an `int`. There are two possible regions of overflow here.

Comment: Sorry, of course, I misunderstood. OP mentions that `c` is 15 though.

Answer (score 0):

`b * 1000` is `int * int`, so integer multiplication occurs and there are higher risk of overflow. (overflow in signed integer aritimetic is *undefined behavior*)

Casting `b` to `float` will also solve this.

```
int a = (int)( (float)b * 1000 / (float)c + .5f );
```

Comment: but I was observing an overflow for values as low as 9. 9*1000 is barely overflow worthy.

Comment: How do you explain an overflow if `b` is between 9-12? 9000-12000 does not overflow an `int`.

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook What do you mean? `9.9` cannot be stored to `int`.

Comment: That was not a decimal point. It was a full stop. I will rephrase:
but I was observing an overflow for values as low as `9` | 
`9*1000` is barely overflow worthy.